# Quicker way of typing out if statements?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say i have...

```
if (value1 == 1 || value1 == 3 || value1 == 6) {
//Things happen
}
```

Since it's referencing value1 each time, is there a quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

An alternative is:

```
switch (value1)
{
case 1:
case 3:
case 6:
    // Things happen
}
```

But it's not "quicker"!

Comment: That is probably a more efficient way of doing it, which is probably the word i should've used. I'll look into switches. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Tell me what you think about my answer.

Comment: I'd stick with the if statement... this also works but I think it's not that readable or obvious what is ment.

Comment: @Bastian: In this particular case, I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch statement:

```
   switch (value1)
   {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 6:
        //Things happen
        break;
      case 4:
        //Something else happens
        break;
      default:
        //Something else happens
   }
```

This is useful if you were otherwise going to have a lot of if statements checking the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean doing something like:

```
if (value1 in {1, 3, 6}) ...
```

then no, you can't do anything like that. Objective-C doesn't have any sort of set operators for basic types. There are other ways to write your code, though, so that you can do a similar operation quickly. For example, if the number of possible values isn't too large, you can use bit positions:

```
if (value1 & (0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20)) ...
```

The compiler will probably OR those constants together at compile time, so the whole comparison takes only as long as a bitwise AND operation.

Comment: Unless the set of numbers contains every single number with any one of those bits set, which is so unlikely as to be essentially impossible, the bit-based approach is going to be totally wrong.

Comment: @smorgan, I think you misunderstand. Perhaps I should have written it like this: `(1<<1 | 1<<3 | 1<<6)`. This approach is practical if the values range from 0 to 63, perhaps more, and that's often a very useful set.

Comment: @Oli, the numbers in the first example are 1, 3, 6. The numbers in the second set are 2^1, 2^3, 2^6. The whole point here is to use bit positions to represent values; it's not an uncommon technique in C-based languages.

Comment: Ah, right.  It's ok, I understand using bit-masks for flag checking.  It just wasn't at all obvious how it related to the example in question.